# Hardware Design Question Related to IMU VDD, VDDIO and IO pins

Tags: spi, level-shifting, imu, level-translation

I am working on a flight controller design using ICM-20789, an IMU from TDK. As most of the components are powered by 3V3 source, so I am thinking connect IMU_VDD to 3V3 and VDDIO to 1V8 source same as the recommended design.

However, is the level translator needed? As the absolute maximum rating table suggests that IMU IO can take VDD+0.5V can I just connect SPI and I2C pins to MUC without level translation?

[image: Absolute Maximum Ratings]

[image: Recommended Design]

Comment: Yes, you need the level translator. Absolute maximum ratings simply mean that the chip won't be damaged, not that it will operate correctly.

Comment: Since you aren ‘t using tri-state you could use an RN divider R network to reduce V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MAX3378 is expensive $4.

Since you are not using tri-state (uni-directional) you can cost-reduce this with a series R>R shunt to divide voltage /2.

Alternatively, to reduce the drive voltage within spec, you could use two Resistors to /2 the output voltage using equal R=220 (e.g.) for high speed conversion. These come in a variety of arrays that cost < $0.10.  E.g. two pullup resistor networks could be used as pullup/down to divide by two.